# Type definition for react-navigation-v6 <Stack.Group>

Tags: typescript, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

**I am not able to determine the correct type definition for a Stack group with screens (see `TestStack.Group` and the nested `TestStack.Screen`).**

The navigation stack:

```
const TestStack = createNativeStackNavigator<TestStackParamList>();
function TestNavigator() {
  return (
    <TestStack.Navigator initialRouteName="TestScreen">
      <TestStack.Screen
        name="TestScreen"
        component={TestScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: true, title: "", headerTransparent: true }}
      />
      <TestStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: "modal" }}>
        <TestStack.Screen name="TestModal" component={TestModal} options={{ title: "" }} />
      </TestStack.Group>
    </TestStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

As part of the root stack defined as:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  TestStack: NavigatorScreenParams<TestStackParamList> | TestScreenParams;
...
}
```

```
export type TestStackParamList = {
  TestScreen: TestScreenParams;
  TestResultScreen: TestScreenParams;
  StaticContentScreen: StaticContentParams;
};
```

```
export type TestScreenParams = {
  param1: string;
  param2: string;
};
```

---

I've tried the below (and a few other combinations..)

```
export type TestStackParamList = {
  TestScreen: TestScreenParams;
  TestResultScreen: TestScreenParams;
  StaticContentScreen: StaticContentParams;
  TestModal: RouteGroupConfig<TestStackGroupParamList, NativeStackNavigationOptions>;
};

export type TestStackGroupParamList = {
  TestModal: { simplified: string; type: ModalType };
};
```

I am getting this linter error:

```
Type '({ children, navigation, route, }: TestModalProps) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<TestStackParamList, "TestModal"> | undefined'.
```

The error is clear, but I am not able to figure out the right "combination" of navigation types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need of special typings for Screens in Stack Groups: consider them like those without the Stack Group. So `TestStackParamList` could simply be like the following.

```
export type TestStackParamList = {
  TestScreen: TestScreenParams;
  TestResultScreen: TestScreenParams;
  StaticContentScreen: StaticContentParams;
  TestModal: { simplified: string; type: ModalType };
};
```

Below there's the complete file with typings (I made some assumptions about code missing in the question). You can also check in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-type-definition-for-react-navigation-v6-stack-group-35pwew?file=/src/TestStackNavigation.tsx) that there's no type issues with this code.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  createNativeStackNavigator,
  NativeStackScreenProps
} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

/* SECTION: SCREENS */
function TestScreen() {
  // TODO: Return the actual component
  return null;
}

type TestModalProps = NativeStackScreenProps<TestStackParamList, "TestModal">;

function TestModal({ route }: TestModalProps) {
  const { simplified, type } = route.params;
  // TODO: Use the route params and return the actual component
  return null;
}
/* END SECTION: SCREENS */

/* SECTION: NAVIGATION */
// TODO: Replace with actual modal types
type ModalType = "type1" | "type2";

export type TestScreenParams = {
  param1: string;
  param2: string;
};

export type TestModalScreenParams = {
  simplified: string;
  type: ModalType;
};

export type TestStackParamList = {
  TestScreen: TestScreenParams;
  TestResultScreen: TestScreenParams;
  StaticContentScreen: StaticContentParams;
  TestModal: TestModalScreenParams;
};

const TestStack = createNativeStackNavigator<TestStackParamList>();

export function TestNavigator() {
  return (
    <TestStack.Navigator initialRouteName="TestScreen">
      <TestStack.Screen
        name="TestScreen"
        component={TestScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: true, title: "", headerTransparent: true }}
      />
      <TestStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: "modal" }}>
        <TestStack.Screen
          name="TestModal"
          component={TestModal}
          options={{ title: "" }}
        />
      </TestStack.Group>
    </TestStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it worked. I've tried that previously, but the Component props (of the component that I was passing in) were wrong and I didn't pay enough attention to it. By default, the screen component expects `{route, navigation}:RootTestScreenProps<"TestModal">`